# Command to remove "Everyone" user from Disk Permissions in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, script, batch-file

What would be a suitable command to remove `Everyone` user from Disk Permissions in Windows?

Comment: Are you trying to speak to your computer? This is a website, you can't give commands here. But assuming it's meant as a question, you should try the Windows Property dialog and it's usually a better idea to remove those permissions on a folder than on a drive as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have this installed :- [Sysinterals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)
In Powershell :-

```
[C:\]psgetsid Everyone

PsGetSid v1.44 - Translates SIDs to names and vice versa
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

SID for BUILTIN\Everyone:
<SID>

icacls <drive>\*.* /remove:g *<SID> /T
```

Again, test it on a smaller subset of folders first.

---

This works, but has been replaced by icacls, detailed above.

Not actually powershell, but you could run

```
cacls.exe *.* /e /g Everyone:n
```

Which should set everyone to no permission, across the whole disk.

Be sure to test this on a single file/folder first, to ensure it doesn't break access for other users.

I've used the following link as a reference.
 [Microsoft TechNet Library Cacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx)

Comment: Windows version is Windows 2012, since Cacls is depracated. I am trying with icacls.exe. But I want to remove the "Everyone" user altogether from the permissions list.

Comment: Updated the answer to also include icacls.

Comment: @SwethaSetty Just FYI... I've noticed in the past that sometimes you need to run the `icacls <drive>\*.* /remove:g "everyone" /T` command twice. The first run will remove all granted permissions and then the second run will remove all denied permissions but that's the same syntax I've used in similar situations as Steven suggests but I put "everyone" there in place of the SID with the wildcard in case you had trouble interpreting from that what to use.

Comment: The "Everyone" user is still seen. The disk still shows the user in its Sharing>Advanced Permissions tab.

Comment: Do they have permissions assigned?

Comment: Yes, the permissions are still intact.